routes restrictions on laravel
I have a laravel code that if the login does a bind it logs the user in and matches the email he has on the session with the emails i have on CheckUserRole model and middleware.
my doubt is how to restrict on routes.php based on the role from that table:
class CreateUserRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('role');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_roles');
    }
}


class CheckUserRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
    {
        // Check if the user is authenticated
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Retrieve the user's role from the user_roles table
            $user = Auth::user();
            $userRole = DB::table('user_roles')->where('email', $user->email)->value('role');

            // Check if the user's role is one of the allowed roles
            if (in_array($userRole, $roles)) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        // Redirect or handle unauthorized access
        return redirect()->route('login'); // Redirect to login route if the user is not authorized
    }
}

if i for example do the following :
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Supervisor']], function () {
        // Define routes for the supervisor role...
    });

it's always logging out the user when i click in any of the routes, eventhough the email its logging in is a Supervisor email.
im expecting to be able to restrict on routes scince i dont have access to user model or middleware, it just binds and if matches , retrieves email and stores it on session

Please try to add logs to determine if the CheckUserRole modal is actually running as you'd expect. Something must have gone unexpectedly in your stack. You need to at least determine which before getting any closer to a fix.
